# JQuery won't work after Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why does my JQuery only work on the first page of my endless scroll? I am using the .on() method...isn't this not supposed to happen with .on()?

Here is my JQuery in custom.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.article_description', function() {  
     $('.article_description').toggleClass("article_description article_description_full");
  }); 
});
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="article_well_main" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="photo_well col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12"> 
        <img src="<%=asset_path "#{article.image}">
    </div>

  <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12" >
    <h4 class="article_title"><%= link_to article.title, "#{article.location}", :target => "_blank"%></h4> 

    <p class="article_description"><%= article.description.html_safe%></p> 
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
         <p class="article_location" style="font-size:10px"><%= article.date_published %>  &nbsp|&nbsp <%= link_to article.source, "http://www.#{article.source}", :target => "_blank"%> </p>
       </div>

       <div class ="article-notes col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
         <%=article.notes%>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you type into the console, I'm sure that jQuery is working just fine. You're probably telling your endless scroll plugin to initialize before you load jQuery or something of that nature. Have you tried putting your code after the 'complete' section in your AJAX call?

Comment: On the first call your toggle removes class `article_description` and adds `article_description_full`. So selector on `article_description` does not work anymore.

Comment: Thanks! fixed that and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example, please run the code snippet below,

```js
$(document).on('click', '.article_description', function() {  
  $(this).toggleClass("article_description_full");
});
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   console.log(st);
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
     // downscroll code
     if ((Math.round(st/100)*100) % 800 == 0) {
  $("#wrapper").addClass("spinner");
  // insert a cloned article_well_main after 2 seconds
  setTimeout(function(){
    var that = $(".article_well_main:first").clone(false);
           that.insertAfter(".article_well_main:last").find(".article_description")
           .removeClass("article_description_full");
    that.hide().fadeIn();
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("spinner");
  }, 2000); 
     }
   } else {
      // upscroll code
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
.article_description {
 border:1px solid red;
 background-color: #DDD;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.article_description.article_description_full {
 min-height: 100px;
}
.spinner {
 background: url("https://i1.wp.com/cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/galleriffic/2.0.1/css/loader.gif") no-repeat bottom center;
}
.container-fluid {
 min-height: 800px;
 padding-bottom: 800px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .container-fluid {
     min-height: 1200px;
     padding-bottom: 1200px;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
  <div class="article_well_main well" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="photo_well col-lg-5 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12"> 
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/d5c5ca719e82ca5a2afd0ff1702c221c?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG">
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" >
        <h4 class="article_title"><%= link_to article.title, "#{article.location}", :target => "_blank"%></h4> 

        <p class="article_description"><%= article.description.html_safe%></p> 
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
            <p class="article_location" style="font-size:10px"><%= article.date_published %>  &nbsp|&nbsp <%= link_to article.source %> </p>
          </div>
          <div class ="article-notes col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <%=article.notes%>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Note: I am using a timer to mimic an endless scroll

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using on method please use bind method

try the following code

```html
$(document).bind('click', '.article_description', function() {
     $('.article_description').toggleClass("article_description article_description_full");
  });
```

The above working perfectly for me

let me know if you have any query

Thanks